# ggplot grouped bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset:

```
  Year Generated Rejected
1 2012 133118208  7256986
2 2013 289487598 49652610
3 2014 192232775 31765480
4 2015  40434968  2513930
```

I am trying to generate a grouped bar chart that will have `Year` on the x axis and a numerical scale on the y axis to show the generated Vs rejected year-wise.

I am confused what I should set my y axis to? I have not tried using the `spread()` function yet, as I am hoping there might be an easier way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to arrange the data in the proper format for plotting:

```
library(reshape2)
df1 <- melt(df, id = "Year")
```

Or you could use the `tidyr` package:

```
library(tidyr)
df1 <- gather(df, variable, value, -Year)
```

Which may be easier to understand if you are not familiar with `melt()`

Basically, it says: *"Gather all the variables in `df` except `Year`, calling the new key column `variable` and the new value column `value`"*

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(Year, value)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

[image]

If you prefer to format numbers with commas separating thousands:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(df1, aes(Year, value)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Values", labels = comma)
```

[image]

Comment: Beaupre: a good answer.  OP can also pick colors and change the legend title, among many other choices:  ggplot(df1, aes(Year, value)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), position = "dodge", stat = "identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "forestgreen")) + 
  labs(fill = "Legend")

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Though I was hoping to avoid reshaping the data, but guess that was the only way.