# Odd ggplot stacked bar output

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I've got dozens of plots far more complicated but for some reason my brain isn't working this one out..

Given a dataframe and code of...

```
# libraries
 require(ggplot2)
 require(dplyr)
 require(tidyr)

# create data
 data <- data.frame("When"=c("(2008 - 2009)","(2010 - 2011)","(2012 - 2013)","(2014-2015)","Cannot Remember"),
                    "Friend"=c(2,7,15,3,0),
                    "News Website"=c(2,10,8,3,1),
                    "Printed Newspaper"=c(0,1,3,0,0),
                    "Academic Paper"=c(0,0,2,0,0),
                    "Online Forum"=c(6,16,25,6,1),
                    "Cannot Remember"=c(1,3,7,2,1)
                    )

# reshape to long format
 data <- gather(data,var,val,2:7) 

# plot stacked bar
 ggplot(data[which(data$val>0),],aes(x=When, Y=val)) +
       geom_bar( aes(fill=var))
```

I am getting a stacked bar and even tried reshaping as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909242/ggplot-grouped-bar-chart) BUT the bars (and sub bars) are definitely not the values in the table, topping out at 6 and I cannot for the life of me see why.  So far 2 hours of fiddling and I cannot get this right.

[image: Not the plot I was expecting]

Please can someone save my addled brain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you have `Y` in upper case in your `aes`, and you have to set `stat = "identity"`, try :

```
ggplot(data[which(data$val>0),],aes(x=When, y=val)) +
  geom_bar( aes(fill=var), stat = "identity")
```

Comment: TWO HOURS!!!!! For an uppercase "Y".. arghhhhhh!!!!!!!   Thanks for spotting that